# converting kilograms to pounds using coded values in R with values under the same variable

Tags: r

I am requesting help to see the best way to convert kilograms to pounds in R using coded values.

For example,

The values in the variable for pounds are denoted 0-999 and the values for kilograms are denoted 9000-9998 where the first number of "9" denotes that it is in kilograms.

I am struggling to convert the kilogram coded values into pounds.

so far I was thinking of using the mutate function with the ifelse function but cannot figure out how I should convert it.

The current attempted thought process is shown below.

mutate(WEIGHT = ifelse(WEIGHT == 9000:9998,...,...))

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about

`data %>% mutate(across(WEIGHT, ~ifelse(. < 1000, ., (. - 9000) * 2.2))` ?

(if the numeric value is less than 1000 assume that it represents a weight in pounds and, leave it alone; otherwise, subtract 9000 (to get the weight in kg) and multiply by 2.2 to convert to pounds)

At least, that's how I'm interpreting your coding.

Comment: The problem is that there are other values mixed in the variable to represent pounds. For example, values 000 - 999 represent pounds but value 9998 in the same variable would equal 998 kilograms.

Comment: That's what my code is assuming.  It would help to give a [mcve], i.e. an example of some input data and the output you would expect from it.

Comment: can you comment/edit your question to show why this code *doesn't* do what you want?

Comment: I ended up being able to make it work!  Thank you though!

Comment: If you solved your own problem you are (strongly) encouraged to post the solution!